# How to approach SSL encryption with file uploads

Tags: php, ssl, upload, directory, javascript

I added SSL to a site I'm putting together, and it caused a huge error that I have no idea how to approach. The user logs into the site, which allows them to upload files to the server into a directory based on their username. Adding SSL didn't affect the ability to log in or register an account, but the upload function is completely broken (it now does nothing). I'm wondering if the directory info would get altered by the SSL code and would cause the upload screen to access incorrect/nonexistent directories?

I'm using the blueimp file-upload with minor modifications.

I'm not a web developer by any means. This is my first encounter with SSL and I know very little about how to approach the issue. I've been trying to figure out a good way to generate logs so I can see what's running and where and am not even sure how to do that. Any resources that might help me understand what SSL may be doing to cause the issue, or even just some proper debugging techniques in php would be great. I've been beating my head against a wall on this one, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to get logs that actually give me useful information.  How should I go about properly generating useful log files?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of your webserver logs rather than your programming logs. If you need help with debugging your own program, this is very much the wrong site.